# In any base, if a non-normal (or non-simply-normal) integer is added to a normal real number between 0 and 1, is that sum still a normal real?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My thought is that the distribution of numbers will not be affected, therefore the sum is still a normal real. I think I may be missing something, though.

Another thought that I had is that the non-normal reals form a set of measure zero in the reals (and similarly the non-normal reals between $0$ and $1$ form a set of measure zero on the real interval $[0,1]$), and the set formed by the union $\left(\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z},k\in\mathbb{R}} (n+k)\right)$ should generate $\mathbb{R}$, and thus the non-normal subset of $\left(\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z},k\in\mathbb{R}} (n+k)\right)$ is also of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$. I still think I may have overlooked something, or may have committed an error in my reasoning.

Comment: What is the def'n of a normal real?

Answer (score 0):

In base $b>2$ , given a normal number $r$, construct $s$ as follows : If $r$ has digit $b-1$ at the current position, wrtite digit $0$, otherwise digit $1$. Clearly , $s$ is not normal. But $r+s$ has no digit $0$, so is not normal either.

Not sure in the case $b=2$